# MySQL 8 update high contention workload performance issue

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I have a table in MySQL named ticket.

When I try to update the ticket table like

```
update ticket set available_ticket = available_ticket - 1 where ticket_id = ?
```

The above query works fine and takes all the applicable indices.

I have an API that does exactly like this. In MySQL 5.7.1, for 1200 RPS, the update query runs in less than 10 ms.

Recently, we upgraded to MySQL8, and the performance for the above query was less than 10 ms till 600 rps and it started degrading post that and for 1200 RPS, the performance is around 7 s.

I looked at the explain plan and it looks fine.

Imagine there are million tickets are up for sale, we will be updating the same row to decrement the available tickets once after every purchase. The contention is about updating the same row and same column by multiple times.

Can anyone help me with what can be checked further to analyse the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Am I correct in saying that `ticket` has lots of columns?  And one of them (`available_ticket`) has a lot of activity?  And there are queries from other connections that are accessing the other columns -- possibly getting involved in the "contention"?  And there are several indexes on the table?

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE ticket`.

I recommend moving `available_ticket` into a separate table:

```
CREATE TABLE available_ticket_counts (
    ticket_id ...,
    available_ticket ...,
    PRIMARY KEY (ticket_id) )
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

This will isolate the contention away from the other columns.

(Caveat: Without knowing a lot more info, I cannot guarantee that this will help.  It could lead to `JOINs` that exacerbate the problem instead of helping it.)

Perhaps...  Split the tickets up between 100 tables.  When grabbing a ticket, pick a table at random (or by some other means).  Yes, the algorithm gets messy when one of the tables runs out of tickets, but there are tickets in some of the other tables.

Comment: Nope. Contention is multiple threads are trying to update the column/same row.

Imagine there are million tickets available and everyone trying to update the same row after a ticket is booked.

Comment: @jagannathanrajagopalan - Is this some kind of online game where thousands of users try to grab tickets at soon as possible after the game announces that it is time?  Can one connection grab more than one ticket?  If so does it have to grab the tickets one at a time?

Comment: @jagannathanrajagopalan - I added an algorithm that may improve concurrency (at the expense of code complexity).

Comment: Can you tell me what is the algorthm you have added? Yes its something like online game where there are few tickets available and then they go and update

Comment: @jagannathanrajagopalan - Please describe the ticket processing further.  Include answers to the questions I asked above.  Also, how much more popular do you expect the game to become?  How many tickets are available; how many users; will a user repeatedly ask for more tickets; etc, etc.  The details of an "algorithm" will depend on many of such metrics.

Comment: its one of the very popular ticketing systems in the world. in over 5 mins, we can expect 500K tickets to be sold. We will have around 5 M users logged to book these tickets.

Comment: Do you need to record which ticket is sold to which user?  Can a user buy multickets at a single time?  2K updates per second is a very high rate; I need more details -- else I will give you a solution that will fail in some other way.

Comment: I just have to update the inventory count. not map against the user.